# How pass variable php in javascript in function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

so i want try pass variable php to function javascipt where variables is

```
<?php $code1=""; ?>
```

and for function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $code1 = $(this);
            $txt=new Array();
            var $code1 = <?php echo $code1("code1"); ?>;
            $(function(){
                $('#go').on('click',function(){
                    console.log($('form').serialize());
                })

                $('body').on('keydown','.last',function(){
                    $('.last').removeClass('last');
                    $('#go','body').before(
                    '<table><tr><td><input class="last" type="text" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value=" SHOULD BE HERE "></td></tr></table>');          
                })
            })
        </script>
```

should be value is ="$code1" so i try value= "`<?php echo $code1; ?>`" but it's cant can help me pls?

Comment: php executes on the server, javascript executes on the client. you cannot have JS set/modify a php variable.

Comment: @MarcB I think they want it the other way around, to use a php variable in JavaScript, which is just fine

Comment: Thx for comment, yes i want use php variable in javascript function, not must variable php, i just dont know how to fill in the value = "$code1" where $code1 is variable php. sry newbie for javascript programmers

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode()` is what you want, but all the quotes and what not are handled for you by the JSON-encoding.  Don't add more quotes.  Also, it's easiest if in your JavaScript, you assign stuff to their own variables.

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Also, I recommend that you don't simply concatenate data into HTML like this.  Otherwise, you're lacking escaping for HTML which can cause ambiguity and injection problems.

```
$('<input>').val(data);
```

Comment: thx for comment i already try var code1 = <?php echo json_encode($code1); ?>;, but what if used in a javascript function? how writing inside if value = "" ?

Comment: Can you re-write, to type text and blank values​​, sorry my starter javascript so i write $('#code1').attr("",YourValue) what is in YourValue?

Comment: @Vilthering It's best to not just embed it directly into a JavaScript function... you're making hard-to-read code.  But if you did, nothing changes.  `$('#code1').val(<?php echo json_encode($val); ?>);`.  No need for those extra quotes.

Comment: I done try var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>; and $('#code1').val(<?php echo json_encode($val); ?>); but tht function is failed, no working.

Comment: @Vilthering It does work.  Without knowing the context, I won't be able to help you.  You should post a new question with the specific code you've tried, along with the specific error you're getting.