# How use variable php in javascript for 2 fuction?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i want use 2 function java Script for automatically add the new column when the contents and autosuggestion, this for example coding automatically add the new column when the contents http://jsfiddle.net/3jLbm9sp/1/ so when i try input in first column, he will be give auto suggestion for first column and add new column(second column) and give autosuggestion too. but i cant This is all my coding :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <form method = "POST" action="text.php" >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link href="css/inputpo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <!--For Auto Suggestion -->
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#code1").autocomplete({
                source: 'autosuggest.php',
                select:function(event, ui){
                            $('#descrip1').val(ui.item.descrip1);                           
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <!--For Auto Add New Colomun-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($code1); ?>;
            $txt=new Array();
            $(function(){
                $('#go').on('click',function(){
                    console.log($('form').serialize());
                })

                $('body').on('keydown','.last',function(){
                    $('.last').removeClass('last');
                    $('#go','body').before(
                    '<table><tr><td><input class="last" type="text" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value=""></td>
```

`');

                    })
                })`

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
$code1="";
if($_GET) {
$code1      = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code1'] : '';
$descrip    = isset($_POST['descrip1']) ? $_POST['descrip1'] : '';

}
?>
        <div class="isi">
                <table height="51" border="0" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td width="99" align="center" label for="suggestionbox">
                        <div align="center">Code</div></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">Description</div>
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="code1" name='code1' value="<?php echo $code1;?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                <input  class="last"  type="text" id="descrip1" name='descrip1' value="">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
                <input id="go" name="" type="submit" /></td>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if i only use autosuggestion it's work but cant add new column, and if i use add new column, I can not get auto suggestion, when i check the fail Function is in here

```
type="text" id="code1" name="code'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" value="">
```

if value is empty ="" its work for add new column,and where for autosuggestion variable (PHP) is $code1, so i try write in value=""> does anybody know how to write php variable inside a javascript function? can use another like ajax, but i don't know how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How pass variable php in javascript in function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265139/how-pass-variable-php-in-javascript-in-function)

Comment: this for all coding, because another say post new question with all coding?